# How to insert multiple instance in Django Rest API @api_view?

Tags: arrays, json, django, django-rest-framework

How can insert multiple data at once in Django rest API with Json array

Json Arry

```
[{
        "order_token": "8000253120",
        "name": "lg",
        "mobile_number": "9739615236",
        "address1": "arjun",
        "city": "bangalore",
        "state": "karnataka",
        "pincode": "562122"
    },
    {
        "order_token": "8000253125",
        "name": "iphone",
        "mobile_number": "807312784",
        "address1": "V H Palya",
        "city": "bangalore",
        "state": "karnataka",
        "pincode": "562122"
    }
]
```

when creating with @api_view i get error : list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
@api_view(['POST',])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))
def create_order(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = {}
        serializer = OrderSerializer(data=request.data, many=isinstance(request.data, list))
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            data['success'] = 'created successfully'
            return Response(data=data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializer

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Can you share serializers and model code too?

Comment: @AkashJoshi added sir

Comment: I think your model field has an `IntegerField` but in JSON array, you are passing an integer as a string. Or share model code too. Thanks